# Trouble with syntax for SELECT in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have tried the following syntax, which seems to work fine on SQL when I use Oracle SQL Developer. However, when I use the code in MySQL, I get ther error "Something went wrong!".

```
   $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Table1 NATURAL JOIN (SELECT ID, SUM(row2) FROM table2 GROUP BY ID) NATURAL JOIN (SELECT ID, COUNT(col1) FROM Table2 WHERE ID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ID)")
   or die("Something went wrong!");
```

Is there a difference in syntax in this case, or could it be anything else I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Run your query diectly at mysql to get besser error messaging or have a look onto error code of mysqli_query (isn't this function deprected?)

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 NATURAL JOIN
      (SELECT ID, SUM(row2) FROM table2 GROUP BY ID) NATURAL JOIN
      (SELECT ID, COUNT(col1) FROM Table2 WHERE ID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ID)
```

MySQL supports `NATURAL JOIN` (I don't recommend using it, but that is another matter).  Unlike Oracle, you need to have table aliases on the tables, essentially names for them.  You may also need column aliases.  I always use them, so I don't know if they are needed.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1 NATURAL JOIN
      (SELECT ID, SUM(row2) as cnt_row2
       FROM table2
       GROUP BY ID
      ) t2row NATURAL JOIN
      (SELECT ID, COUNT(col1) as cnt_col1
       FROM Table2
       WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY ID
      ) t2col1
```

You can actually simplify this query:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.cnt_col1, t2.cnt_row2
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
      (SELECT ID, COUNT(col1) as cnt_col1, SUM(row2) as cnt_row2
       FROM Table2
       GROUP BY ID
      ) t2
      ON t1.id = t2.id
```

The filtering on `ID IS NOT NULL` has no effect, because a `NULL` value will not be included in the `join`.

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL all the Sub queries that are used in the `FROM` part need an alias name. In your case its missing. And I don't use `NATURAL JOIN` because using other specific `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` clarifies the condition and scenario. So may be you could rewrite your query like this to make it work:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, SUM(row2) FROM table2 GROUP BY ID) a
ON a.ID = Table1.ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, COUNT(col1) FROM Table2 WHERE ID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ID) b
ON b.ID = Table2.ID;
```